# Pages must fill the whole ViewPager2 (use match_parent) while i set it to match parent

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-viewpager2

I use `viewPager2` in my app with `custom adapter` and in layout i use my `viewpager2` in `linearLayout`.
i set the `height` and `width` of my `viewpager2` to `matchParent`, and i also set it to `matchParent` in java code, and set `attachToRoot` to `false`, but i still get this error when i lunch my app.
how can i solve this problem?

this is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/vp_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my viewpager2 code:

```
mAdapter = new adapter_vp2_home(getActivity(), ls);

    vp_home.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    vp_home.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);

    vp_home.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and this is the log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pages must fill the whole ViewPager2 (use match_parent)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2$4.onChildViewAttachedToWindow(ViewPager2.java:270)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildAttached(RecyclerView.java:7713)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:857)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:8753)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8711)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8699)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1645)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4141)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3853)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4410)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:526)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:945)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2961)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2648)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1785)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7832)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: please post the full stack trace log

Comment: @Zain i edit my post.

Comment: try to set  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` on the LinearLayout

Comment: @Zain I try it but it gives me the same error and log

Comment: why weight android:layout_weight="0.7"?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown cause i want my viewpager fill 70% of my screen. I also deleted it but it give the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just solve this problem by match parent the custom layout of my custom viewpager2

Answer (score 2):

set width and height in your adapter item of ViewPager2 match_parent

Answer (score 1):

Set LayoutParams for view:

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Not *vp_home.setLayoutParams*, just delete it

Answer (score 1):

This Problem can be solved by taking view height as "`match_parent`" of both **Viewpager** & **row_layout.xml** (whatever you have xml for pager)

**SAMPLE CODE:**

**ViewPager2:**

```
   <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/vpager_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

**Row Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/size_10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/size_10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_6dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/banner_big_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_height="240dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, my viewholder layout should have had `match_parent` only.

Answer (score 0):

You can change **wrap_content** to **match_parent** in your **custom layout XML** file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragment.PracticeFragment">
```